# Horizontal and vertical scroll in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a grid that contains many collection views with horizontal scrolling. I want to add vertical scroll because later views can not see. How Can I design? Which controls should I use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the Grid in a **[ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview)**

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

      <Grid>
           
           //... 
      </Grid>

</ScrollView>
```

> contains many collection

In addition, If the content of Grid is similar , you could also put them in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) .

Comment: Thank you so much. I added a ScrollView and it works. But high vertical extra space between the collection view. How can I remove it?

Comment: I got it. I defined heightRequest for each collection view.

Comment: Happy coding :)